# spring roo build fails because of missing dependency org.springframework.build.aws.maven

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-roo

I just cloned a fresh copy of spring-roo from github and tried to mvn install it. But that failed because a dependency was missing.

I suspect the solution to work for other cases of missing build in spring projects as well.

```
Missing:
----------
1) org.springframework.build.aws:org.springframework.build.aws.maven:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE

  Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

  Then, install it using the command: 
      mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.springframework.build.aws -DartifactId=org.springframework.build.aws.maven -Dversion=3.1.0.RELEASE -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

  Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
      mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=org.springframework.build.aws -DartifactId=org.springframework.build.aws.maven -Dversion=3.1.0.RELEASE -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

  Path to dependency: 
        1) org.springframework.roo:org.springframework.roo.root:pom:1.2.5.BUILD-SNAPSHOT
        2) org.springframework.build.aws:org.springframework.build.aws.maven:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solve this problem by adding the spring releases repository to the `pom.xml` of `spring-roo`.

```xml
...
<repositories>
   ...
   <repository>
            <id>repository.springframework.maven.release</id>
            <name>Spring Framework Maven Release Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.springframework.org/release</url>
    </repository>    
</repositories>
...
```